# MS Office Type Library is forwards compatible?

Tags: c#, api, ms-office, compatibility

If I build a C# app with the MS Office 12.0 Object Library (MS Office 2010), will users with MS Office 2016 or newer be able to use my C# app or do I have to build a separate version of my app for each major release of MS Office?

Comment: Office apps are *backwards* compatible, so your app targeting an old version can still work with the new version.  Forward compatibility does not exist, nobody can predict the future.  Just try it.